# Abbreviating a term containing "hypotheses"

Tags: abbreviations

A paper I’m writing refers frequently to a group of anthropological hypotheses, and I would like to abbreviate “anthropological hypotheses.” However, because hypotheses is plural, I’m debating whether to use (AH) or (AHs).

I suspect that (AH) may be technically correct, but In my opinion, (AHs) is better because it reminds the reader that I’m talking about more than one hypothesis. I was therefore wondering what forum-members thought about this.

Thanks very much for your opinions

Comment: AHs is the right choice, and why do you think AH is technically correct? There's a difference between ATM and ATMs.

Comment: Perhaps the best dictionary of initialisms/acronyms lists dozens of expansions of AH, but not this, even in the 'least rarely used' category. There are not a vast number of hits for the expansion “anthropological hypotheses” on Google. Usually, an initialism pluralises by the addition of a lower-case s, but there may be situations where this is not the case, the terminal s being 'coded for by the last letter of the abbreviation'. With little-used initialisms, local practice should be followed. This is arbitrary rather than a matter of standard English, so off-topic on ELU....

Comment: For instance, 'President of the United States' is abbreviated POTUS not POTUSs.

Comment: The use of AHs as the plural of AH is normal and correct. It does not matter if AH is well-known acronym or not; all that matters is that you define it in your prose on its first use there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: But in POTUS, the relevant noun to be pluralised is **president**, not **state**. And if there were several of them, they'd be POTUSs (or POTUSes or POTUS's or whatever). In OP's context, the abbreviation is **AH = anthropological hypothesis** - so to reference several such ***hypotheses,*** you'd use AHs (or AHes or AH's, according to taste).

Comment: Ugh. I vote against this kind of abbreviation. It does not make reading easier. You don't need to repeat "anthropological," since that is obviously the type of hypotheses (once described). I would simply refer to "the hypotheses" when needed, after defining your subject. If a name has been applied to sets of hypotheses, such as "the late-arrival hypotheses" or the "pre-Columbian hypotheses" and both need to be referenced, then I might use "LAH" and "PCH" to distinguish them, and avoid real wordiness.

Comment: @FF An SOS not an SOSs or an SOS's. The initialism, like an acronym, has become lexicalised up to a point, with the final s incorporated. The crux of this question is (a) is AH an acceptable initialism here and (b) if so, is it a standardised abbreviation of “anthropological hypothesis”, “anthropological hypotheses”, or both?

Comment: An initialism whose expansion is already plural is NICT (New Information and Communication Technologies). Unusual, but shows lack of universal patterning. _And more common that AH = anthropological hypothesis?/es?_ ([AllAcronyms](https://www.allacronyms.com/NICT/New_Information_and_Communication_Technologies))

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much for the very informative discussion. It was more than I had hoped for.